# Div element's html into textarea

Tags: jquery, html, markitup

I am using markItUp editor in my webpage and I wanted to do on the fly editing to authorized users. When user double click to post Jquery turns div into textarea and

```
#textarea.markItUp();
```

converts the textarea to markitup editor. However my problem is post has too many < p> tags and when I convert div into textarea it ends up like this :
http://jsfiddle.net/D3v7F/ (click change)

But I want to show < p> as new paragraph. how to achive this ? and < strong> tags into [b]strong's inner text[/b]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    var html = $('.change p').html();

    $('.change').replaceWith('<textarea>'+html + '\r\nNew paragraph</textarea>').html().focus();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D3v7F/3/

Comment: but I want <p> as new paragraph :(

Comment: Is this what you mean? Try now.

Comment: ye Hanlet this is what I mean.. Oh so i should convert <p> as \r\n

Comment: \r\n will add a new line one the textarea element.

Comment: I just figure that out, thanks bro, simple regex may handle this and for <strong> tags convert to bbcodes can also done with regex.